# By the age of 18, I (decided / had decided) not to go to university

Tags: tense

Are both these versions of the sentence equally grammatical? If so, is there any significant difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the story you're telling. If you're telling me something that happened in the past and this is just a brief recount of that story then "**By the age of 18 I decided not to go to the university"** is correct.
Now if you're telling me something that happened in the past with a correlation to the future then I would say "**by the age of 18 I had decided not to go to the university".**

Here's an example:

By the age of 18 I decided not to go to the university and ended up going back to my dad's house. (**The action happened in the past, and it stayed there. There's no need to add extra information after that**.)

By the age of 18 I had decided not to go to the university and thought it was a better idea to join the military and that's how I became a captain in the Marines. (**The action happened in the past but the effects of that action influenced the character's future.**)

They're not equal grammatically.

**I had decided** not only means that something happened in the past but it also asks for more explanation, more information from the writer whereas **I decided** just tells of something that happened in the past and had no role in the future. It stayed in the past.

Answer (score 0):

As with many questions about the use of tenses in English, both are possible, and perfectly normal. The difference is not in the events described, but in how the writer is choosing to relate them temporally.

If the writer uses the past perfect, the writer is looking back on the events from a later time in the past. If you start a story "By the age of 18, I had decided not to go to university", the expectation is that you will continue telling of what happened at some later time than that when you made that decision: probably when you were 18, but maybe later.

The simple past does not have that dual focus of time: it simply says that the events were in the past, and does not set the temporal focus. The story might continue from the time of your decision, or from some later time, or even from now.